# Scrape value of li tags in separate variables using preg_match function in php

Tags: php, preg-match

There are 3 li tags with span title class Length, Width and Height as below:

```
 <li style="padding-left: 20px">
<span class="title">Length:</span>
<span class="value">1.5</span>
</li>
<li style="padding-left: 20px">
<span class="title">Width:</span>
<span class="value">2.5</span>
</li>
<li style="padding-left: 20px">
<span class="title">Height:</span>
<span class="value">3.5</span>
</li>
```

I want extract the class values in 3 separate variables for example
$length = 1.5, $width= 2.5, $height= 3.5 and insert into 3 separate columns in my database

Currently I am writing the code as below:

```
$length = (preg_match('#<span class="title">\s*Length:\s*</span>\s*<span class="value">\s*(.*?)\s*</span>#si', $prod, $m)) ? $m[1] : '';

$width  = (preg_match('#<span class="title">\s*Width:\s*</span>\s*<span class="value">\s*(.*?)\s*</span>#si', $prod, $m)) ? $m[1] : '';

$height = (preg_match('#<span class="title">\s*Height:\s*</span>\s*<span class="value">\s*(.*?)\s*</span>#si', $prod, $m)) ? $m[1] : '';
```

But the problem I am facing is all 3 values are getting inserted in the first column. Can anyone help me in this regards.

I am adding some portion of the code:

```
if (!preg_match_all('#<div class="product-show">(.*?)</li>#s', $content, $m)) break;


        foreach ($m[1] as $prod) {

            $length = (preg_match('#<span class="title">\s*Length:\s*</span>\s*<span class="value">\s*(.*?)\s*</span>#si', $prod, $m)) ? $m[1] : '';
            $width  = (preg_match('#<span class="title">\s*Width:\s*</span>\s*<span class="value">\s*(.*?)\s*</span>#si', $prod, $m)) ? $m[1] : '';
            $height = (preg_match('#<span class="title">\s*Height:\s*</span>\s*<span class="value">\s*(.*?)\s*</span>#si', $prod, $m)) ? $m[1] : '';

            $size = (preg_match('#<strong>\s*Size:\s*</strong></span>\s*<span class="value">\s*<strong>\s*(.*?)\s*</strong>#si', $prod, $m)) ? $m[1] : '';
            $sku = (preg_match('#<span class="title">\s*<strong>\s*SKU:\s*</strong>\s*</span>\s*<span class="value">\s*<strong>\s*(.*?)\s*</strong>#si', $prod, $m)) ? $m[1] : '';
            $prod_url = (preg_match('#<h2 class="product-name"><a href="([^"]*?)"#si', $prod, $m)) ? $m[1] : '';
            $img = (preg_match('#<img[^>]*?data-src="([^"]*?)"#si', $prod, $m)) ? $m[1] : '';
            scrape_product($prod_url, $img, $cat, $sku, $size, $length, $width, $height);
            $done++;
        }
```

Every thing is working except the length, width and height

Comment: *'getting inserted in the first column'* So you have an issue in extracting or inserting? b

Comment: You are using ternary operators on each pattern. If _true_, you are setting the value. But you are setting the same value `$m[1]` everywhere. So you `$length` and `$width` and `$height` will all return the same.

Comment: Aside from that, you shouldn't use Regular Expressions for this. Instead, you should parse the html: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better using `DOMDocument` and `XPath` expressions rather than trying to use a regular expression which are notoriously bad at parsing html. Consider something like this perhaps:

```
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML( $strhtml );
$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
$col=$xp->query('li span[ @class="value" ]');
if( !empty( $col ) ){
    foreach( $col as $node )echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```